# position of "auf" in sentence with conjugated verb aufhören

Tags: verb, word-order, verb-usage, separable-verb

As far as I know conjugated separable verbs standing by themselves place the separable particle at the end of the sentence. I got the following sentences from my textbook:

Hört sofort mit eurem Geschrei auf!

Hör auf mich zu schlagen!

why is the particle auf from the verb aufhören not at the end in the second sentence ?

Answer (score 2):

Mind the correct punctation:

> Hört sofort mit eurem Geschrei auf!
>
> Hör auf, mich zu schlagen!

The second example is a main clause, followed by an infinitive clause.

> Hör mich zu schlagen auf!

is also possible but an unusual way to put it.

Comment: There is no comma in my texbook. The english traslation would me " Stop  beating me". The context is two kids fighting.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver If I remember correctly, the comma there was mandatory before the 1996 spelling reform, but might be optional since then.

Comment: @juancarlosvegaoliver the comma is not mandatory, it is optional IIRC, but it is extremely helpful for German learners, so I would use it.

Comment: the comma is facultative and even in cases where it isn't, it is "sofern ein einfacher Infinitiv mit zu (ohne weitere Wörter oder Satzteile) vorliegt und keine Missverständnisse entstehen können <§ 75 E1>." Now, if the reflexive pronoun is parsed as part of the Verbal P,hrase then the infinitive is "einfach", though the VP isn't. Which overall calls into question whether there is a full clause. "Hört sofort auf mit eurem Geschrei" doesn't need a comma either.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the infinitive object of the prefix verb, i.e. "Hör auf mit was? Zu schreien!".
Further examplex:

> Ich habe vor, abzureisen.

"Ich habe abzureisen vor" is possible but pretty awkward.

---

Another example of such a behavior of separated verbs is prepositional object of a verb, e.g. "Hör auf mit dem Geschrei" would be more idiomatic than "Hör mit dem Geschrei auf", but both are possible. A somwhat similar example: "pass auf auf dich" and "pass auf dich auf" (en. "take care").

Comment: Are "vor" and "auf" marking the object, i.e. "Die Infinitivgruppe wird mit einem hinweisenden Wort angekündigt oder wieder aufgenommen <§ 75 (3)>."?

Comment: Sure, but I don't think its that simple. It is not the case where there are no prepositions involved in the object, e.g. "Schnallen Sie Ihr Kind an". 
Oder: Ich lade meine Dateien hoch.      "Ich lade hoch(,) meine Dateien" ist auch möglich, aber irgendwie zu umgangssprachlich und locker.